# Is it okay to have more vertices on the hand then the rest of the body?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to create a female model but I'm having a quite a hard time to create the hand from the wrist so I made it separated. Is it okay to do it with in the future I'm trying to rig them?

Example like this:
[image: Hand Example]

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ok? What problem is this causing?

Comment: Currently there's no problem. Just wanna know if there will be any problem if I wanted to rig it.

Comment: It makes total sense to have more vertices on the hand. It is more complex and has many more moving elements than other parts of the body.